# Twisted is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, python-wheel

Navigate to the directory that contains the .whl file and type:

```
pip install Twisted-17.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

and I got:

> Twisted-17.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

I also tried 64 bit version had the same error message:

```
pip install Twisted-17.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

I have checked:

```
pip install wheel
```

Requirement already satisfied: wheel in

```
c:\users\yang\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

My OS: `Windows 7, 64 bit`

Answer (score 1):

It's so obvious. I didn't realize that this "cp27" in the file name means the python version. Twisted-17.9.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is for python 2.7 but I had 3.6.

Comment: It would be pretty cool if pip told you what the incompatibility were in plain terms though, wouldn't it